# Actual meaning of redefinition of function with inheritance in C++

Tags: c++, inheritance

**Code From Bruce Eckel, Thinking in C++**

```
class A {
    int i;
  public:    
    A(int ii) : i(ii) {}
    ~A() {}
    void f() const {}
};

class B {
    int i;          
  public:
    B(int ii) : i(ii) {}
    ~B() {
    void f() const {}
};

class C : public B {
    A a;
  public:
    C(int ii) : B(ii), a(ii) {}
    ~C() {}  // Calls ~A() and ~B()
    void f() const {  // Redefinition
        a.f();
        B::f();
    }
};

int main() {
    C c(47);
}
```

FOR THIS CODE HE SAYS,

> The function C::f( ) redefines B::f( ), which it inherits, and also calls the base-class version. In addition, it calls a.f( ). Notice that the only time you can talk about redefinition of functions is during inheritance; with a member object you can only manipulate the public interface of the object, not redefine it.

What does he mean ?

The function `C::f()` is simply calling `f()` of `B` through the scope resolution operator.  This is because it is inherited and a function with the same name is also present in `C`.  `A`'s function `f()` is called through the object defined in class `C`.

**So, where is the  redefinition of function `f()` as Eckel says?**

Comment: I think you are mistaken by the word **Redefinition**. Here **redifinition** means **overwriting** method f() in derived class C.

Comment: so you mean just like writing it again ?

Comment: What I meant is... when you are using Inheritance in your class design you mostly try to bring all the common features in base class, and only bring distinguishing stuffs in the derived class. Suppose i have base class Vehicle that has a method to update vehicles wheel material component. Now you derive vehicle to two classes. BiCycle and Cars. Then you need to overwrite this update method for Cars as you may be requiring to update the axle info in that methods for cars, but there is nothing like axle in bicycle so in that case still use base class vehicles method.

Comment: In simple words you need to overwrite when you want something extra or completely new behavior than base class.

Comment: s/overwrite/override/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the class `C` is derived from `B`, the function `C::f()` overrides the function `B::f()` by defining its own version.  If you declare an object of type `C` and call its `f()` function, it will execute `C::f()` which can be completely independent of `B::f()`.  So the base-class function has been redefined.

Note that class `C` also contains a member of type `A`, which also has a function `f()`, and that `C`'s implementation of `f()` happens to call `a.f()`.  So `C` can provide its own `f()` with a different *interface*, but it cannot *change* `A`'s implementation.

Answer (score 1):

The difference is what would happen if you had *not* written the function `C::f`, but still called `f` on an object of (static) type `C`, as in

```
C c;
c.f();
```

Without the existence of `C::f`, this would call `B::f` (found because `B` is a base class of `C`), but not `A::f` (because that's just a member object). Thus the existence of the function `C::f` causes a change in the semantics of the call `c.f()`.

However note that `C::f` does not *override* `B::f` because `B::f` is not virtual. That is, the following code will still call `B::f`, not `C::f`:

```
C c;
B& b(c);
b.f();
```

If `B::f` were virtual, `C::f` would override it and that code would call `C::f`. However since `B::f` is not virtual, `C::f` does not override it, and therefore the code above does call `B::f()`.

BTW, I do not agree with the terminology of Bruce Eckel here. In my view, "redefine" would mean to replace the definition. However `C::f` does not replace the definition of `B::f`, it just hides it.

Comment: +1 C::f does not _override_ B::f because B::f is not virtual, nor does it _redefine_ B::f because that's nonsense.

Answer (score 0):

If you removed the definition of "C::f", you could still call "C::f()" because it would be inherited. But in this example, he has instead chosen to provide C with it's own implementation of "f". This "hides" the B::f function from anyone dealing with an object of type "C". But it is termed a "redefinition" because the definition is also hidden from anyone viewing an object of type "C" through a downcast to a parent type.

Consider

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class A { void x() { cout << "A::x" << endl; } };
class A1 : public A {}; // No redefinition.
class A2 : public A { void x() { cout << "A2::x" << endl; A::x(); } };

int main(int argc, const char** argv)
{
    A1 a1;
    A2 a2;

    cout << "a1: "; a1.x();
    cout << "a2: "; a2.x();

    A2* pa2 = &a2;
    cout << " pa2: "; pa2->x();
    A* pa = (A*)a2;
    cout << "pa: " ; << pa;

    return 0;
}
```

That last - the cast - is the most important part. You can only call A2's "x" by having an object of type A2 or a descendant that hasn't also redefined it. Imagine if you have created the following:

```
class Account {
   float m_balance;
public:
    Account() : m_balance(0) {}
    void Close() {} // What to do when the account is closing.
}

class SecureAccount : public Account {
    Transaction* m_transactionInProgress;
public:
    SecureAccount() : Account(), m_transactionInProgress(nullptr) {}
    void Close() {
        if(m_transactionInProgress) {
           m_transactionInProgress->Finish();
        }
    }
};
```

The whole point of inheritance is to let you use lowest common denominators, so in this case, it is very likely you are going to be calling

```
/*account*/p -> Close();
```

Which can only see the definition of "Close" in Account. So when you add a SecureAccount* to the vector, and try to close it while it still has an open transaction you are going to lose money.

In order to see how to solve this, read on to the explanation of virtual functions.